# Have a VM send mail to itself

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtual-machine, sendmail, exim

I have a VM with exim4 configured for receiving mail and passing it to a PHP script. I would like to configure it for testing so that the VM could send mail to itself. So if I send a mail with sendmail to a specific domain, it should not leave the VM and be captured by exim as if it was coming from the outside. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes this is possible and this is default behaviour for local domains.

Comment: Currently if I send a mail using sendmail it goes live. Not sure what you mean by local domains?

Comment: Standard exim's configuration (ACLs, routers and transports) is built with assumption that domainlist named `local_domains` exists and contains all domains hosted on the given localhost. For those domains no SMTP-forwarding occurs but local delivery is launched. That is the standard default behaviour.